# How to approach identifying Melampsora species?

Tags: species-identification, mycology, parasitology

I'd like to figure out which species of Melampsora that is growing on this European aspen. What would be the right approach? Would a microscope or other tool help? Is there even more than a single species that attacks aspen?

These photos were taken of an aspen leaf in Stockholm.

[image]
[image]